# Polyfit for two variables

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

I have a kind of data and want to find the equation(poly coeff) of given data. For example equation for given sample data is simple `a^2*b+10`

```
a\b    5    10    15
________________________
3|    55   100   145
4|    90   170   250
5|   135   260   385
6|   190   370   550
```

I checked for`polfit`but It only works for one variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Dusty Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2174/dusty-campbell) pointed out you can use the `fit` function. To do this you have to build a mesh with your data

```
a = [3 4 5 6];
b = [5 10 15];
[A, B] = meshgrid(a, b);
C = (A.^2).*B + 10;
```

and then call `fit` with a custom equation

```
ft = fittype('p1*a^2*b + p2', 'independent',{'a','b'}, 'dependent','c');
opts = fitoptions('Method','NonlinearLeastSquares', 'StartPoint',[0.5,1]);
[fitresult, gof] = fit([A(:), B(:)], C(:), ft, opts);
```

As you'll see the solver converges to the correct solution `p1 = 1`, `p2 = 10`.

Answer (score 0):

[`polyfitn`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn) should help...

Another approach: In the general case of non-linear data fitting you can easily use [`lsqnonlin`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the [`fit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) function from the [Curve Fitting Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit-postprocessing.html). Or perhaps [`polyfitn`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn) created and shared by another Matlab user.