# Equivalent of `polyfit` for a 2D polynomial in Python

Tags: python, math, numpy, linear-algebra, polynomial-math

I'd like to find a least-squares solution for the `a` coefficients in

```
z = (a0 + a1*x + a2*y + a3*x**2 + a4*x**2*y + a5*x**2*y**2 + a6*y**2 +
     a7*x*y**2 + a8*x*y)
```

given arrays `x`, `y`, and `z` of length 20. Basically I'm looking for the equivalent of [`numpy.polyfit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) but for a 2D polynomial.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440188/polyfit-for-two-variables) is similar, but the solution is provided via MATLAB.

Comment: no sorry, I added it in there.

Comment: sklearn has [kernel ridge regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge.html#sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge) but I'm not sure whether you can set `alpha` to 0. Would that work for you?

Comment: Scipy's Splines might be useful: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: The kernel ridge regression provides a nice model, but I don't see how to display the coefficients.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is an example showing how you can use `numpy.linalg.lstsq` for this task:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, copy=False)
Z = X**2 + Y**2 + np.random.rand(*X.shape)*0.01

X = X.flatten()
Y = Y.flatten()

A = np.array([X*0+1, X, Y, X**2, X**2*Y, X**2*Y**2, Y**2, X*Y**2, X*Y]).T
B = Z.flatten()

coeff, r, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)
```

the adjusting coefficients `coeff` are:

```
array([ 0.00423365,  0.00224748,  0.00193344,  0.9982576 , -0.00594063,
        0.00834339,  0.99803901, -0.00536561,  0.00286598])
```

Note that `coeff[3]` and `coeff[6]` respectively correspond to `X**2` and `Y**2`, and they are close to `1.` because the example data was created with `Z = X**2 + Y**2 + small_random_component`.

Comment: What is your goal with each of these lines? 

`Z = X**2 + Y**2 + np.random.rand(*X.shape)*0.01`
`A = np.array([X*0+1, X, Y, X**2, X**2*Y, X**2*Y**2, Y**2, X*Y**2, X*Y]).T`

Why do you flatten this matrices?

`X = X.flatten()`
`Y = Y.flatten()`

Comment: @xeon123 the goal with the expression for `Z` is only to create a sample of data to test the surface fit. I had to flatten `X` and `Y` such that `A` becomes a 2D array, which is the format needed by the `lstsq` solvers.

Answer (score 14):

Based on the answers from @Saullo and @Francisco I have made a function which I have found helpful:

```
def polyfit2d(x, y, z, kx=3, ky=3, order=None):
    '''
    Two dimensional polynomial fitting by least squares.
    Fits the functional form f(x,y) = z.

    Notes
    -----
    Resultant fit can be plotted with:
    np.polynomial.polynomial.polygrid2d(x, y, soln.reshape((kx+1, ky+1)))

    Parameters
    ----------
    x, y: array-like, 1d
        x and y coordinates.
    z: np.ndarray, 2d
        Surface to fit.
    kx, ky: int, default is 3
        Polynomial order in x and y, respectively.
    order: int or None, default is None
        If None, all coefficients up to maxiumum kx, ky, ie. up to and including x^kx*y^ky, are considered.
        If int, coefficients up to a maximum of kx+ky <= order are considered.

    Returns
    -------
    Return paramters from np.linalg.lstsq.

    soln: np.ndarray
        Array of polynomial coefficients.
    residuals: np.ndarray
    rank: int
    s: np.ndarray

    '''

    # grid coords
    x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    # coefficient array, up to x^kx, y^ky
    coeffs = np.ones((kx+1, ky+1))

    # solve array
    a = np.zeros((coeffs.size, x.size))

    # for each coefficient produce array x^i, y^j
    for index, (j, i) in enumerate(np.ndindex(coeffs.shape)):
        # do not include powers greater than order
        if order is not None and i + j > order:
            arr = np.zeros_like(x)
        else:
            arr = coeffs[i, j] * x**i * y**j
        a[index] = arr.ravel()

    # do leastsq fitting and return leastsq result
    return np.linalg.lstsq(a.T, np.ravel(z), rcond=None)
```

And the resultant fit can be visualised with:

```
fitted_surf = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d(x, y, soln.reshape((kx+1,ky+1)))
plt.matshow(fitted_surf)
```

Comment: The suggested edit queue for this answer is full which sounds like there are over 500 edits people have tried to submit. For anyone else who comes across this, `polyval2d` in the bottom portion should be `polygrid2d` as noted in the comments. `soln` is the first portion of the return value, again as noted in the comments. I'd also suggest putting full code to call your code/ plot, but that's too much for a comment. I really appreciate your answer, I just think it might be easier for people to use if there was a more robust usage example.

Comment: I also believe the line `for index, (j, i) in enumerate(np.ndindex(coeffs.shape)):` should be `for index, (i, j) in enumerate(np.ndindex(coeffs.shape)):` since values where kx!=ky throws an error

Answer (score 6):

Excellent answer by Saullo Castro. Just to add the code to reconstruct the function using the least-squares solution for the a coefficients,

```
def poly2Dreco(X, Y, c):
    return (c[0] + X*c[1] + Y*c[2] + X**2*c[3] + X**2*Y*c[4] + X**2*Y**2*c[5] + 
           Y**2*c[6] + X*Y**2*c[7] + X*Y*c[8])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use scikit-learn for this.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, copy=False)
X = X.flatten()
Y = Y.flatten()

# Generate noisy data
np.random.seed(0)
Z = X**2 + Y**2 + np.random.randn(*X.shape)*0.01

# Process 2D inputs
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
input_pts = np.stack([X, Y]).T
assert(input_pts.shape == (400, 2))
in_features = poly.fit_transform(input_pts)

# Linear regression
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
model.fit(in_features, Z)

# Display coefficients
print(dict(zip(poly.get_feature_names_out(), model.coef_.round(4))))

# Check fit
print(f"R-squared: {model.score(poly.transform(input_pts), Z):.3f}")

# Make predictions
Z_predicted = model.predict(poly.transform(input_pts))
```

Out:

```
{'1': 0.0012, 'x0': 0.003, 'x1': -0.0074, 'x0^2': 0.9974, 'x0 x1': 0.0047, 'x1^2': 1.0014}
R-squared: 1.000
```

**Notes**

I used the `fit_intercept=False` argument when defining the linear regression model because the polynomial features by default include the bias term `'1'`. Alternatively, you could disable that using

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
```

and then use a regular `LinearRegression` model with an intercept coefficient:

```
model.intercept_  # 0.0011741137800872492
```

Comment: `get_feature_names_out()` -> `get_feature_names()` https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/category_encoders/issues/348 - didn't follow all the discussion but dropping the _out makes it work in my version

Comment: The code still works for me in scikit-learn version 1.2.1.  What version are you using?

Comment: My `sklearn.__version__` is 0.23.2, 0.23.2-5ubuntu6 apt installed in ubuntu 22.04 - so the change is going the other way, older versions don't have the _out()

Answer (score 1):

Note that if `kx != ky` the code will fail because the `j` and `i` indices are inverted in the loop.

You get `(j,i)` from `enumerate(np.ndindex(coeffs.shape))`, but then you address elements in `coeffs` as `coeffs[i,j]`. Since the shape of the coefficient matrix is given by the maximum polynomial order that you are asking to use, the matrix will be rectangular if `kx != ky` and you will exceed one of its dimensions.