# How can I use multiple dimensional polynomials with numpy.polynomial?

Tags: python, numpy, math, polynomials

I'm able to use `numpy.polynomial` to fit terms to 1D polynomials like `f(x) = 1 + x + x^2`. How can I fit multidimensional polynomials, like `f(x,y) = 1 + x + x^2 + y + yx + y x^2 + y^2 + y^2 x + y^2 x^2`? It looks like numpy doesn't support multidimensional polynomials at all: is that the case? In my real application, I have 5 dimensions of input and I am interested in hermite polynomials. It looks like the polynomials in `scipy.special` are also only available for one dimension of inputs.

```
# One dimension of data can be fit
x = np.random.random(100)
y = np.sin(x)
params = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, y, 6)
np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval([0, .2, .5, 1.5], params)

array([ -5.01799432e-08,   1.98669317e-01,   4.79425535e-01,
         9.97606096e-01])

# When I try two dimensions, it fails. 
x = np.random.random((100, 2))
y = np.sin(5 * x[:,0]) + .4 * np.sin(x[:,1])
params = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyvander2d(x, y, [6, 6])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-5409f9a3e632> in <module>()
----> 1 params = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyvander2d(x, y, [6, 6])

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.pyc in polyvander2d(x, y, deg)
   1201         raise ValueError("degrees must be non-negative integers")
   1202     degx, degy = ideg
-> 1203     x, y = np.array((x, y), copy=0) + 0.0
   1204 
   1205     vx = polyvander(x, degx)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,2) into shape (100)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like polyfit supports fitting multivariate polynomials, but you can do it by hand, with `linalg.lstsq`. The steps are as follows:

1. Gather the degrees of monomials `x**i * y**j` you wish to use in the model. Think carefully about it: your current model already has 9 parameters, if you are going to push to 5 variables then with the current approach you'll end up with 3**5 = 243 parameters, a sure road to overfitting. Maybe limit to the monomials of __total_ degree at most 2 or three...
2. Plug the x-points into each monomial; this gives a 1D array. Stack all such arrays as columns of a matrix.
3. Solve a linear system with aforementioned matrix and with the right-hand side being the target values (I call them z because y is confusing when you also use x, y for two variables).

Here it is:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random((100, 2))
z = np.sin(5 * x[:,0]) + .4 * np.sin(x[:,1])
degrees = [(i, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]  # list of monomials x**i * y**j to use
matrix = np.stack([np.prod(x**d, axis=1) for d in degrees], axis=-1)   # stack monomials like columns
coeff = np.linalg.lstsq(matrix, z)[0]    # lstsq returns some additional info we ignore
print("Coefficients", coeff)    # in the same order as the monomials listed in "degrees"
fit = np.dot(matrix, coeff)
print("Fitted values", fit)
print("Original values", y)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I actually want to do this for arbitrary-degree hermite polynomials, which have a more complicated structure, hence my want to use the numpy.polynomial API.

Comment: Well, whatever the functions are (polynomials or not) the idea stays the same: plug x-points into function, get a column; stack the columns; solve the system with LSQ solver.

Comment: It's weird that numpy doesn't supply a way to make multidensional polynomials in a simple way. I thought the option would be available and I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Your answer is so close to answering my question. I just need some programic way of constructing `matrix` for different families of polynomials.

Comment: You have to have a way to loop over the polynomials, whatever they are, and evaluating each polynomial on the set of points that you have. Details depend on how the polynomials are represented

Answer (score 5):

I got annoyed that there is no simple function for a 2d polynomial fit of any number of degrees so I made my own. Like the other answers it uses numpy lstsq to find the best coefficients.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import lstsq
from scipy.special import binom

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def _get_coeff_idx(coeff):
    idx = np.indices(coeff.shape)
    idx = idx.T.swapaxes(0, 1).reshape((-1, 2))
    return idx


def _scale(x, y):
    # Normalize x and y to avoid huge numbers
    # Mean 0, Variation 1
    offset_x, offset_y = np.mean(x), np.mean(y)
    norm_x, norm_y = np.std(x), np.std(y)
    x = (x - offset_x) / norm_x
    y = (y - offset_y) / norm_y
    return x, y, (norm_x, norm_y), (offset_x, offset_y)


def _unscale(x, y, norm, offset):
    x = x * norm[0] + offset[0]
    y = y * norm[1] + offset[1]
    return x, y


def polyvander2d(x, y, degree):
    A = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyvander2d(x, y, degree)
    return A


def polyscale2d(coeff, scale_x, scale_y, copy=True):
    if copy:
        coeff = np.copy(coeff)
    idx = _get_coeff_idx(coeff)
    for k, (i, j) in enumerate(idx):
        coeff[i, j] /= scale_x ** i * scale_y ** j
    return coeff


def polyshift2d(coeff, offset_x, offset_y, copy=True):
    if copy:
        coeff = np.copy(coeff)
    idx = _get_coeff_idx(coeff)
    # Copy coeff because it changes during the loop
    coeff2 = np.copy(coeff)
    for k, m in idx:
        not_the_same = ~((idx[:, 0] == k) & (idx[:, 1] == m))
        above = (idx[:, 0] >= k) & (idx[:, 1] >= m) & not_the_same
        for i, j in idx[above]:
            b = binom(i, k) * binom(j, m)
            sign = (-1) ** ((i - k) + (j - m))
            offset = offset_x ** (i - k) * offset_y ** (j - m)
            coeff[k, m] += sign * b * coeff2[i, j] * offset
    return coeff


def plot2d(x, y, z, coeff):
    # regular grid covering the domain of the data
    if x.size > 500:
        choice = np.random.choice(x.size, size=500, replace=False)
    else:
        choice = slice(None, None, None)
    x, y, z = x[choice], y[choice], z[choice]
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(
        np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 20), np.linspace(np.min(y), np.max(y), 20)
    )
    Z = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d(X, Y, coeff)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection="3d")
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.2)
    ax.scatter(x, y, z, c="r", s=50)
    plt.xlabel("X")
    plt.ylabel("Y")
    ax.set_zlabel("Z")
    plt.show()


def polyfit2d(x, y, z, degree=1, max_degree=None, scale=True, plot=False):
    """A simple 2D polynomial fit to data x, y, z
    The polynomial can be evaluated with numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array[n]
        x coordinates
    y : array[n]
        y coordinates
    z : array[n]
        data values
    degree : {int, 2-tuple}, optional
        degree of the polynomial fit in x and y direction (default: 1)
    max_degree : {int, None}, optional
        if given the maximum combined degree of the coefficients is limited to this value
    scale : bool, optional
        Wether to scale the input arrays x and y to mean 0 and variance 1, to avoid numerical overflows.
        Especially useful at higher degrees. (default: True)
    plot : bool, optional
        wether to plot the fitted surface and data (slow) (default: False)

    Returns
    -------
    coeff : array[degree+1, degree+1]
        the polynomial coefficients in numpy 2d format, i.e. coeff[i, j] for x**i * y**j
    """
    # Flatten input
    x = np.asarray(x).ravel()
    y = np.asarray(y).ravel()
    z = np.asarray(z).ravel()

    # Remove masked values
    mask = ~(np.ma.getmask(z) | np.ma.getmask(x) | np.ma.getmask(y))
    x, y, z = x[mask].ravel(), y[mask].ravel(), z[mask].ravel()

    # Scale coordinates to smaller values to avoid numerical problems at larger degrees
    if scale:
        x, y, norm, offset = _scale(x, y)

    if np.isscalar(degree):
        degree = (int(degree), int(degree))
    degree = [int(degree[0]), int(degree[1])]
    coeff = np.zeros((degree[0] + 1, degree[1] + 1))
    idx = _get_coeff_idx(coeff)

    # Calculate elements 1, x, y, x*y, x**2, y**2, ...
    A = polyvander2d(x, y, degree)

    # We only want the combinations with maximum order COMBINED power
    if max_degree is not None:
        mask = idx[:, 0] + idx[:, 1] <= int(max_degree)
        idx = idx[mask]
        A = A[:, mask]

    # Do the actual least squares fit
    C, *_ = lstsq(A, z)

    # Reorder coefficients into numpy compatible 2d array
    for k, (i, j) in enumerate(idx):
        coeff[i, j] = C[k]

    # Reverse the scaling
    if scale:
        coeff = polyscale2d(coeff, *norm, copy=False)
        coeff = polyshift2d(coeff, *offset, copy=False)

    if plot:
        if scale:
            x, y = _unscale(x, y, norm, offset)
        plot2d(x, y, z, coeff)

    return coeff


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 100
    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(n), np.arange(n))
    z = x ** 2 + y ** 2
    c = polyfit2d(x, y, z, degree=2, plot=True)
    print(c)
```

Comment: Are you going to submit a pull request?

Comment: To numpy? Never done that before, will try to do it next week.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have misunderstood what `polyvander2d` does and how it should be used. `polyvander2d()` returns the pseudo-Vandermonde matrix of degrees `deg` and sample points `(x, y)`.

Here, `y` is not the value(s) of the polynomial at point(s) `x` but rather it is the `y`-coordinate of the point(s) and `x` is the `x`-coordinate. Roughly speaking, the returned array is a set of combinations of `(x**i) * (y**j)` and `x` and `y` are essentially 2D "mesh-grids". Therefore, both `x` and `y` *must* have identical shapes.

Your `x` and `y`, however, arrays have *different* shapes:

```
>>> x.shape
(100, 2)
>>> y.shape
(100,)
```

I do not believe `numpy` has a 5D-`polyvander` of the form `polyvander5D(x, y, z, v, w, deg)`. Notice, all the variables here are coordinates and not the values of the polynomial `p=p(x,y,z,v,w)`. You, however, seem to be using `y` (in the 2D case) as `f`.

It appears that `numpy` does not have 2D or higher equivalents for the `polyfit()` function. If your intention is to find the coefficients of the best-fitting polynomial in higher-dimensions, I would suggest that you generalize the approach described here: [Equivalent of `polyfit` for a 2D polynomial in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964913/equivalent-of-polyfit-for-a-2d-polynomial-in-python)

Comment: Thanks! So can I use the API to fit the coefficients of `f(x,y)` using the data I generated?

Comment: @kilojoules See the last paragraph in my just edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I'm interested in the answer you linked to. I would like to make that work for multidimensional hermite polynomials of arbitrary degree.

Comment: @kilojoules I am confident you will be able to do it. I am just afraid that for large number of data points and/or higher dimensionality and/or high polynomial degrees, `lstsq()` used in the linked solution as well as in @if... solution will become unstable. It may be better to derive the system to be solved yourself and solve it using standard `linalg.inv()`.

Answer (score 0):

The option isn't there because nobody wants to do that. Combine the polynomials linearly (`f(x,y) = 1 + x + y + x^2 + y^2`) and solve the system of equations yourself.