# Finding a polynomial regression equasion

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have multiple vaiables and a list of experimental results, and Im wondering what will be the best way to create a polinomial fitting function.

ex :

```
| param1   | param2 | param3| res|
|--------------------------------|
|0.5       | 0.004  |  40   |6.75|
|0.55      | 0.684  |   0   |10.1|
|0.6       | 0.001  | -40   |13.2|
...
```

so far I used python to find the polinomial regsression like so:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0.5 ,0.004 ,40],[0.55, 0.684, 0],[0.6, 0.001, -40]...more parameters values ..]) # matrix describing all parameters
z = [6.75, 10.1, 13.2, ....more results....] # vector to describe all results according to parameters

degrees = [(i, j, k) for i in range(3) for j in range(3) for k in range(3)]  # list of monomials x**i * y**j to use

matrix = np.stack([np.prod(x**d, axis=1) for d in degrees], axis=-1)   # stack monomials like columns

coeff = np.linalg.lstsq(matrix, z)[0]    # lstsq returns some additional info we ignore

fit = np.dot(matrix, coeff)
```

as suggested by #user6655984 here:
[How can I use multiple dimensional polynomials with numpy.polynomial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180041/how-can-i-use-multiple-dimensional-polynomials-with-numpy-polynomial)

Now im trying to understand how to measure the accuracy?
and to determine the max degree of each variable of the polynom.

Comment: Normally result accuracy is measured by cost functions.You can try different square error functions but I couldn't get your question completely.

Comment: well, I gatherd some data from an experiment, and trying to find a polynomial fitting function to describe it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are asking two questions here, so I would suggest you split them up for future users to find them easier. :-)

Comment: Oh got that. I misunderstood because it was saying parameters. As I know parameter is statical coefficients of a function, I think you meant variables in there. If you have 3 variable system basically you can use  TensorFlow logistic regression systems or if you wanna do it by yourself.You can create a function with arbitrary coefficients and rearrange them with a function like a gradient descent. I hope it helps

Comment: Have you had a look at [`numpy.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)? If so, what were the specific problems you encountered?

Comment: im not sure how to use polyfit to find a solution for more then one variable

Answer (score 0):

The best way always depends on your criteria. If you want to minimize the squared error you could use the [numpy function polyfit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html). You can choose the order of the polynomial (in your case 3) and it will return the solution together with the residuals.

You can also use [least squares](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) for this, but then you have to define the matrices yourself. "A" will then be your parameter matrix and b your experimental results.