# How to use scipy.optimize.minimize(...) to find the optimal parameters of z = f(x, y) (like an ellipse)?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, n-dimensional

I am trying to learn how to optimize data fits in higher dimensions using python / `numpy` / `scipy`. Having successfully used scipy to fit a line of the form `y = f(x)`, I tried extending the logic to fit an ellipse of the form `z = f(x, y)`; both are shown below. I'm hoping this approach can be generalized to fit shapes in higher dimensions (ie, sphere).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

## LINE EXAMPLE
npoints = 30
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, npoints)
m, b = 3, -4 # slope, y-intercept
initial_parameter_guess = (2.5, -1)
y = m * x + b # exact line
noise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=x.size)
yn = y + noise # line with noise

def get_residuals(prms, x, y):
    """ """
    return (y - (prms[0] * x + prms[1]))**2

def f_error(prms, x, y):
    """ """
    resid = get_residuals(prms, x, y)
    return np.sum(resid)

result = minimize(f_error, x0=initial_parameter_guess, args=(x, yn))
# print(result)
yf = result.x[0] * x + result.x[1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, yn, color='b', marker='.')
ax.plot(x, yf, color='r', alpha=0.5)
ax.grid(color='k', alpha=0.3, linestyle=':')
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

[image: line-fit example]

Applying this logic to the case of an ellipse,

```
## ELLIPSE EXAMPLE
npoints = 75
theta = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, size=npoints)
a, b = (3, 5)
initial_parameter_guess = (2.5, 6)
xnoise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=theta.size)
ynoise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=theta.size)
x = a**2 * np.cos(theta)
xn = x + xnoise
y = b**2 * np.sin(theta)
yn = y + ynoise

def get_residuals(prms, x, y):
    """ """
    return 1 - ((x/prms[0])**2 + (y/prms[1])**2)

def f_error(prms, x, y):
    """ """
    resid = get_residuals(prms, x, y)
    return np.sum(resid)

result = minimize(f_error, x0=initial_parameter_guess, args=(xn, yn))
# print(result)
```

The `minimize` algorithm via `scipy` does not find the optimal parameters; the following output is shown with `print(result)`:

```
      fun: -4243.611573066522
 hess_inv: array([[41.44400248, 39.68101343],
       [39.68101343, 37.99343048]])
      jac: array([-1496.81719971,  2166.68896484])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
     nfev: 174
      nit: 1
     njev: 42
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([-1.51640333,  2.93879038])
```

I have seen another [solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964913/equivalent-of-polyfit-for-a-2d-polynomial-in-python), which use the matrix formulation of least squares, but the example is a bit difficult for me to follow. Almost all approaches I've seen are based on the approach in the posted link. I'd prefer using `minimize` unless the linear algebra approach was better for a reason that I am currently unaware of.

Anyways, can my approach above be adapted/tweaked in a way that will work and can be generalized for higher dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues with the code . Instead of minimizing the sum of residuals , minimize the sum of squares of residuals. Secondly , elliptic equation should be defined as `x=a*np.cos(theta)` and `y=b*np.sin(theta)`

```
npoints = 75
theta = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, size=npoints)
a, b = (3, 5)
initial_parameter_guess = (2.5, 6)
xnoise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=theta.size)
ynoise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=theta.size)
x = a * np.cos(theta)
xn = x + xnoise
y = b * np.sin(theta)
yn = y + ynoise
def get_residuals(prms, x, y):
    """ """
    return 1 - ((x/prms[0])**2 + (y/prms[1])**2)

def f_error(prms, x, y):
    """ """
    resid = get_residuals(prms, x, y)
    return np.sum(np.square(resid))
result = minimize(f_error, x0=initial_parameter_guess,args=(xn, yn))

result
  fun: 5.85099318913613
 hess_inv: array([[ 0.07025572, -0.02902779],
       [-0.02902779,  0.12040811]])
      jac: array([-5.96046448e-08,  1.19209290e-07])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 48
      nit: 10
     njev: 12
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([3.35248219, 5.13728323])
```