# How to create the polynom for function of two variables using python?

Tags: python, excel, polynomials, polynomial-math, polynomial-approximations

I have two variables - T1 and T2 - and their values. For example:

```
T1=[300,400,500,600,650,700]
T2=[300,400,500,600,700,800]
```

And i know the values of Z variable for each T1,T2 from example above (i obtained Z values from experiment). So i have a 6x6 matrix of Z values (i know Z for T1=300 T2= 300, Z for T1=300,T2=400 values and etc.). So we can say that Z is the function of two variables - T1 and T2. - Z=F(T1,T2)

I can get a polynom from EXCEL for Z=F(T1,T2) if one of the variables (T1 or T2) is fixed. For example:

`Z(T1=300,T2)=a + b*T2+c*T2^2+d*T2^3+e*T2^4`
`Z(T1,T2=300)=f + g*T1+h*T1^2`

Can you show me the correct code in python, which i can use to receive a polinom for that function of two variables. I think, that it should calculate the coefficients of polynom. For example:

If resulting polynom has the next view: `P(T1,T2)= a + b*T2+c*T2^2+d*T2^3+e*T2^4 + g*T1+h*T1^2`,
the python script should calculate the value of coefficients a,b,c,d,e,g,h.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. You have a function (data) of two variables (T1,T2), and you would like to fit a 2-D polynomial to that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are looking for a way to use `polyfit`, but for 2-d array. 
You should use least-squares optimization (`np.linalg.sltsq`). 
The first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964913/equivalent-of-polyfit-for-a-2d-polynomial-in-python) is exactly what you are looking for.