# Fitting polynomial surface to a 3D dataframe representing family of curves

Tags: python, dataframe, curve-fitting, data-fitting, 3d-model

I have a 3-D dataframe representing family of curves: yi=f(xi) which are also depending on a third variable lets say zi (yi=g(xi,zi)) as shown in the graphic below:

[Family Of Curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjF5E.jpg)

The yi data are measurements and each curve is valid on its own.

Now I would like to find out a proper way to fit a plane or surface to this data in order to avoid 2-D bilinear data interpolation.

In general I am trying to do a similar approach as in the link below:

[2D polynomial in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964913/equivalent-of-polyfit-for-a-2d-polynomial-in-python)

With the difference that my x and y data do not have the same dimensions.
What I am looking for is more a solution for this kind of problem:

[2D data fitting Matlab](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/119001-2d-data-fitting-surface)

Comment: Hi, try to think of a good way of encapsulating your data then write a residual function and use `scipy.optimize.leastsq`. If you have programming problems post them.

Comment: Thanks. I already solves this problem by myself. Sometimes it helps just du write down the question.