# Fitting of a 3d polynominal / volume in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, scipy

I'd like to find the best fit (least-squares solution) for the a coefficients in an equation similar to this one:

`b = f(x,y,z) = (a0 + a1*x + a2*y + a3*z + a4*x*y + a5*x*z + a6*y*z + a7*x*y*z)`

x, y, and z are small arrays with a length of about 20. The shown example is for x**k with k=1. I'm looking for a solution up k=3.

I have found this solution for a 2d fit [Equivalent of `polyfit` for a 2D polynomial in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964913/equivalent-of-polyfit-for-a-2d-polynomial-in-python)

Now I'm looking for a similar solution but in 3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You right, similar technic works:

```
import numpy as np

x, y, z = np.random.randn(3, 20)
grid = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij')
x, y, z = np.stack(grid).reshape(3, -1)

b = np.random.randn(*x.shape).reshape(-1)

A = np.stack([np.ones_like(x, dtype=x.dtype), x, y, z, x * y, x * z, y * z, x * y * z], axis=1)

coeff, r, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)
```