# Linear regression with numpy.linalg.lstsq and NaN values for 2d polynomial fitting

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, curve-fitting, least-squares

I want to fit a function

`f:(Weight,Length)-> Z`

to a 2D surface using numpy.linalg.lstsq.
My dataset `Z` is defined in a `(Weight,Length)` plane. However I have erased the values that are not relevant: All absolute values larger than `3.3` is set to `NaN` using:

```
Z=np.where(np.abs(Z)>3.3,np.NaN,Z)
```

I do not want the algorithm to work hard to get a match where it is not important, sacrificing precision where it actually matters.

I have rendered the values I want to fit for illustration. Btw. my model is a 2d polynom.
[image: surface plot of the dataset]

I want to calculate least square roots using numpy. As I have `NaN` values, I have decided to mask them using:

```
Z = np.ma.array(Z, mask=np.isnan(Z)) # Use a mask to mark the NaNs
```

But the call

```
c, r, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(A, Z, rcond=None)
```

Still gives the known error

```
LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares
```

The code itself works if I do not set values to `NaN`.

How can I run the fit with `NaN` values, telling numpy to ignore those?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:
 `np.linalg.lstsq(a.T[paddedMask].reshape(int(np.sum(nanMask)),(xOrder+1)*(yOrder+1)), np.ravel(z)[mask], rcond=None)`

So I had the same issue and the solution is rather simple, so I want to share it, as I thought this wasn't going to work initially.

`np.linalg.lstsq` takes a matrix of shape (z.size,coeff.size) and data of shape z.size (flattened)

Let the order of the 2d polynominal be determined by `xOrder` and `yOrder`

What I did was to use a mask, pad it and then apply it to the matrix and and the unpadded to the data. A reshaping is needed as otherwise Numpy is flattening an array after use of a mask to 1d.

Padding can be done by using the outerproduct with `np.outer(mask,vector_for_padding)`

```
mask = np.ones(data.size,dtype="bool") #array with only true values
paddedMask = np.outer(mask,np.ones((xOrder+1)*(yOrder+1))).astype(bool) #padding to have the same shape as the matrix we want to remove the e.g. NaN values from
np.linalg.lstsq(matrix.T[paddedMask].reshape(int(np.sum(mask)),(xOrder+1)*(yOrder+1)),np.ravel(data)[mask],rcond=None)
```

The matrix I got was generated using the answer from Paddy here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57923405/8162482

Be aware there is a small mistake of `i` and `j`being switched in the `for` loop (see comment on the post too)

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answers of Sergit and the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32297563/23235094), here is my attempt:

```
def polyfit2d(x, y, f, deg):
    from numpy.polynomial import polynomial
    import numpy as np
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)
    f = np.asarray(f)
    deg = np.asarray(deg)
    vander = polynomial.polyvander2d(x, y, deg)
    vander = vander.reshape((-1,vander.shape[-1]))
    f = f.reshape((vander.shape[0],))
    mask = np.isfinite(f, dtype='bool')
    paddedMask = np.outer(mask, np.ones((deg[0]+1)*(deg[1]+1))).astype(bool)
    a = vander[paddedMask].reshape(int(np.sum(mask)), (deg[0]+1)*(deg[1]+1))
    b = f[mask]
    c = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=-1)[0]

    return c.reshape(deg+1)



x, y = np.meshgrid(weight, length)
coeffs = polyfit2d(x, y, Z, (2,2))
```

I have chosen a polynomial of the 2nd order on both dimensions.